# Why can I not get this code to work in My Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, radgrid

I am using a Telerix RadGrid and cannot seem to get the code to provide the value of a checkbox.  This is my C# code

```
protected void gvMembers_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var editableItem = ((GridEditableItem)e.Item);
        var memberId = (int)editableItem.GetDataKeyValue("UserID");
        int Role = 1;
        CheckBox active = (CheckBox)editableItem["valid"].Controls[0];
        Boolean boolactive = Convert.ToBoolean(active.Checked = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.Cells[0].Text));
        string strFirstName = (editableItem["firstname"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string strLastName = (editableItem["lastname"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string strUserName = (editableItem["username"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string strEmail = (editableItem["firstname"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
```

The code compiles and runs but the checkbox value is always false.  What am I missing?

I have done some more troubleshooting and have discovered this code:

```
CheckBox active = (CheckBox)editableItem["valid"].Controls[0];
```

returns this value {Text = "" Checked = true}

I then added this as my next line of code:

```
 string str = active.Text;
```

and inspected the value of the string it Returns an empty string.

Any Ideas on how I can get the boolean value from the checkbox so I can pass it to the database?

Comment: Didn't understand your condition `active.Checked = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.Cells[0].Text`

Comment: Maybe you meant `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: Are you not storing return of an assignment to bool? I think you meant this: `active.Checked = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.Cells[0].Text);` and then `Boolean boolactive = Convert.ToBoolean(active.Checked);` or another way of doing the same `bool? boolactive = active.Checked = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.Cells[0].Text);`

Comment: Thanks for your comments I have done more checking and it looks like the returned value for the !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.Cells[0].Text) is an empty string.  Looks like I am not getting the value of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by using the following to get the Boolean value:

```
            CheckBox active = (CheckBox)editableItem["valid"].Controls[0];
        Boolean bactive = active.Checked;
```

Thanks for your comments.